# JSON.framework add in xcode

Tags: iphone, json

I have copy JSON.framework in my

Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

both folder and importing

```
#import <JSON/SBJsonParser.h>
```

but when I am using it giving me linking error error
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloThere.app/HelloThere normal i386
cd /Users/samargupta/Desktop/hellothere
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk -L/Users/samargupta/Desktop/hellothere/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/samargupta/Desktop/hellothere/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/samargupta/Desktop/hellothere/build/HelloThere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloThere.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelloThere.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework JSON -o /Users/samargupta/Desktop/hellothere/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloThere.app/HelloThere

ld: framework not found JSON
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

plz tell me where I am wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a JSON-parser by myself. You can use it if you want to by copying the code into your class source.

You use it in this way:

```
NSObject *obj = [self jsonToObj:yourJsonString];
```

It returns a `NSDictionary`, `NSString` or `NSArray` depending on the input. The difference between my parser and others is, that it also accepts numerical keys, which are not allowed in the JSON-standard. I can't guarantee that there are no bugs in it or that it works with all JSON-strings. Please give me some feedback, if it works for you!

```
-(NSObject*)jsonToObj:(NSString *)json {
    int nextOffset;
    return [self jsonToObj:json offset:0 nextOffset:&nextOffset];
}

static int indexOfChar(NSString *str, unichar c, int offset) {
    int length = [str length];
    for (int i = offset; i < length; i++) {
        if ([str characterAtIndex:i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

static int indexOfNonWhitespace(NSString *str, int offset) {
    int len = [str length];
    NSCharacterSet *cSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    for (int i = offset; i < len; i++) {
        if (![cSet characterIsMember:[str characterAtIndex:i]]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

static int indexOfNonNumber(NSString *str, int offset) {
    int len = [str length];
    for (int i = offset; i < len; i++) {
        unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c != '-' && c != '.' && (c < '0' || c > '9')) return i; 
    }
    return -1;
}

static int parseHex(NSString *hexStr) {
    unsigned int result = 0;
    int len = [hexStr length];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result <<= 4;
        unsigned int v = 0;
        unichar c = [hexStr characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            v = c-'0';
        } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
            v = c-'a'+10;
        } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
            v = c-'A'+10;
        }
        result += v;
    }
    return result;
}

-(NSObject*)jsonToObj:(NSString *)json offset:(int)offset nextOffset:(int*)nextOffset {
    offset = indexOfNonWhitespace(json, offset);
    static NSString *jsonExceptionName = @"InvalidJSONException";
    if (offset == -1) {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"no non-whitespace 1" userInfo:nil];
    }
    unichar startChar = [json characterAtIndex:offset];
    if (startChar == '{') {

        NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        int curPos = offset+1;
        while (YES) {
            curPos = indexOfNonWhitespace(json, curPos);
            if (curPos == -1) {
                @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"no non-whitespace 2" userInfo:nil];
            }
            unichar curChar = [json characterAtIndex:curPos];
            if (curChar == ',') {
                curPos++;
                continue;
            } else if (curChar == '}') {
                *nextOffset = curPos+1;
                return result;
            }
            unichar quotChar = curChar;
            if ((quotChar != '\'' && quotChar != '"') || [json characterAtIndex:curPos-1]=='\\') {
                quotChar = 0;
            }
            NSString *key = nil;
            int semiIndex = 0;
            if (quotChar != 0) {
                int quotStart = curPos+1;
                int quotEnd = quotStart;
                while (YES) {
                    quotEnd = indexOfChar(json, quotChar, quotEnd);
                    if (quotEnd == -1) {
                        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"quotation-end not found 1" userInfo:nil];
                    }
                    if ([json characterAtIndex:quotEnd-1] != '\\') break;
                    else quotEnd++;
                }
                key = [json substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(quotStart, quotEnd-quotStart)];
                semiIndex = indexOfChar(json, ':', quotEnd);
                if (semiIndex == -1) {
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"semicolon not found 1" userInfo:nil];
                }
            } else {
                semiIndex = indexOfChar(json, ':', curPos);
                if (semiIndex == -1) {
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"semicolon not found 2" userInfo:nil];
                }
                key = [[json substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(curPos, semiIndex-curPos)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            }

            [result setObject:[self jsonToObj:json offset:semiIndex+1 nextOffset:&curPos] forKey:key];
        }
    } else if (startChar == '[') {

        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

        int curPos = offset+1;
        while (YES) {
            curPos = indexOfNonWhitespace(json, curPos);
            if (curPos == -1) {
                @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"no non-whitespace 3" userInfo:nil];
            }
            unichar curChar = [json characterAtIndex:curPos];
            if (curChar == ',') {
                curPos++;
                continue;
            } else if (curChar == ']') {
                *nextOffset = curPos+1;
                return result;
            }
            [result addObject:[self jsonToObj:json offset:curPos nextOffset:&curPos]];
        }
    } else {
        unichar quotChar = startChar;
        if ((quotChar != '\'' && quotChar != '"') || [json characterAtIndex:offset-1]=='\\') {
            quotChar = 0;
        }
        if (quotChar != 0) {
            int quotStart = offset+1;
            int quotEnd = quotStart;
            while (YES) {
                quotEnd = indexOfChar(json, quotChar, quotEnd);
                if (quotEnd == -1) {
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"quotation-end not found 2" userInfo:nil];
                }
                if ([json characterAtIndex:quotEnd-1] != '\\') break;
                else quotEnd++;
            }
            *nextOffset = quotEnd+1;
            NSString *str = [json substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(quotStart, quotEnd-quotStart)];
            str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
            NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];
            int len = [str length];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
                if (c != '\\') {
                    [result appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1]];
                } else if (i+1 < len) {
                    unichar c2 = [str characterAtIndex:i+1];
                    if (c2 == '\\') {
                        [result appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c2 length:1]];
                        i++;
                    } else if (c2 == 'u') {
                        unichar cUni = parseHex([str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i+2, 4)]);
                        [result appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&cUni length:1]];
                        i += 5;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            int numberEnd = indexOfNonNumber(json, offset);
            if (numberEnd == -1) {
                @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:jsonExceptionName reason:@"number-end not found" userInfo:nil];
            }
            //BOOL isFloat = indexOfChar(json, '.', offset)!=-1;
            NSString *numberStr = [json substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, numberEnd-offset)];
            *nextOffset = numberEnd;
            return numberStr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really very happy with this code. It compile without any error.Thanks for response. Now I get object Actually I am parsing Google Geocoading APIs through this code. Now what I will get in this object.

Comment: hii wow I have done it. Nice parser code. Really it worked well. Again Thanks to You very much for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder in your XCode project name it say "JSON". All the .h and .m files provided by the JSON framework must be in that and well include them in your app, build, run etc etc. Thats how.

Answer (score 0):

The framework folder 'JSON.framework' must be added under each SDK framework folder that you wish to use (iPhone Simulator, iPhoneOS 4.3), or your build will fail with the error that you reported. Alternatively you can just have the folder linked out of your project folder as Bourne mentioned. Either way it Xcode needs to know where the framework is for each type of build your compiling.